# Trouble generating c# linq to entities (EF) query for a 3 table join with or and one table with no key relationships

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

Been trying a bunch of things but can't get anything to work for entity framework. Table structure:

```
Device       DeviceLegacy      BillingDeviceProduct
------       ------------      --------------------
ID           DeviceID          SKU = 123
Num          LegacyID          NID
Name         LegacyUID         SID
```

(extraneous fields omitted)

DeviceLegacy.DeviceID is a foreign key relationship to Device.ID.
DeviceLegacy and BillingDeviceProduct have no relationships in the database but if DeviceLegacy has a BillingDeviceProduct (of SKU=123) either LegacyID will equal NID or LegacyUID will equal SID. Sometimes both values will match. Sometimes they won't, but 1 of those will always match.

SQL:

```
select Num, Name from BillingDeviceProduct bdp
join DeviceLegacy leg on leg.LegacyUID = bdp.SID or leg.LegacyID = bdp.NID
join Device on Device.id = leg.DeviceID
where SKU = 123
```

We have the following but that doesn't handle the condition when both values don't match between DeviceLegacy and BillingDeviceProduct:

```
from device in Devices
join dlegacy in DeviceLegacies
      on device.ID equals dlegacy.DeviceID
      into dl
      from devicelegacy in dl
join bdproduct in BillingDeviceProducts
      on new { devicelegacy.LegacyID, devicelegacy.LegacyUID } equals new { LegacyID = bdproduct.NID, LegacyUID = bdproduct.SID }
      into bdp
      from deviceproduct in bdp
where deviceproduct.SKU == 123
select new { device.Num, device.Name}
```

Answer (score 1):

seems like you could just use the foreign key relationship to exclude one join atleast

```
from bdp in BillingDeviceProducts
where bdp.SKU = 123
from dl in DeviceLegacies.Include("Device")  
where (bdp.SID == dl.LegacyUID || dbp.NID == dl.LegacyID)
select new {
    Num = dl.Device.Num,
    Name = dl.Device.Name
}
```